# Using MSTest in VS 2010

Tags: c#, mstest, visual-studio-2010

In the test results under VS 2010, the Error message column is not very wide.  If I widen the column, the error message is **still** truncated, less than the length of the column.  It will say "Test method   threw exception ..."  Usually the part after the ellipses is what I am interested in.  The only way to see the rest is to open up the test results details.  I have looked over the seetings and don't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the test results dialog is only intended to display a snapshot of each test's results.  You must open the test results details to see all the information.